# How to make custom ripple borderless

Tags: android, android-layout, ripple

Here is my custom ripple

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight">
        <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
</ripple>
```

How do I make it borderless?

Comment: What do you mean by borderless? Are you talking about a button?

Comment: Here is an example of a borderless ripple: `android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"`

Answer (score 6):

As per the [RippleDrawable documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable.html), a ripple will be masked against the composite of its child layers.

In this case, your drawable will be masked by the only item in your ripple.

To have a ripple with no mask, you can define your ripple like so:

```
<ripple android:color="?android:colorControlHighlight" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, while I stumbled upon this question. I have solved my problem easily and there is a code

Btw it works only for cases when height equals width. Else it will be not `?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless`, but ripple oval

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple android:color="@color/grayPrimary" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/mask">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```